# Time complexity of inserting into table with PRIMARY KEY on HASH index

Tags: mysql, hash, time-complexity, unique-index

I just found out that PRIMARY KEYs on HASH-indexed columns in MEMORY tables are themselves HASH indices, as shown by the following:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `test_memory` (
    -> `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    -> KEY `id` (`id`) USING HASH
    -> ) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

mysql> SHOW INDEXES FROM test_memory;
+-------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| test_memory |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | NULL      |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | HASH       |         |               |
| test_memory |          1 | id       |            1 | id          | NULL      |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | HASH       |         |               |
+-------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm wondering then: since PRIMARY KEYs must check for the uniqueness of new entries into their column, does this mean that inserting into `test_memory` is in `O(n)` time, and not `O(log n)` time in the case of a table with a BTREE PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hash structure can identify non-collisions in hash buckets in O(1) time -- theoretically faster then a b-tree.  Hashes are *not* O(n), unless "n" is the number of bits in a single key (usually it refers to the number of records).

Collisions are a problem, because you have to test each value in the hash bucket.  This depends on the underlying implementation.  Sometimes, lists are used; sometimes trees; sometimes another level of hashing.  In any case, if you make a reasonable assuming that the hash table never has more than x collisions, then the complexity is O(x) == O(1).

For this reason, hashes can be faster than b-trees.  That said, b-trees scale better and are easier to manage when they are larger than available memory.